Jquery TreeSelect Post Data
https://github.com/dipson88/treeselectjs
Using the package I mentioned above, I created a select structure in the treeview with jquery.
<div id="my-treeselect"></div>

const domElement = document.querySelector('#my-treeselect') const treeselect = new Treeselect({ parentHtmlContainer: domElement, value: [], options: data });

What I want to do is to post the data I selected in the my-treeselect div with an html form. I want to get the IDs of the selected ones. I couldn't find a way to do this.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? What errors have you encountered? Please provide a [mcve].

Subscribe to the input or close event, that'll get you an array of the currently selected values. https://github.com/dipson88/treeselectjs?tab=readme-ov-file#emits

@C3roe I don't know how to do this. Can you help me with an example?

The example in the "getting started" section on that page shows how to do it. If you want to get those values submitted with the rest of your form - then stick them into a hidden input field or something.

omg I'm blind. treeselect.srcElement.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
console.log('Selected value:', e.detail)
}); This code does what I want. Thank you for everything.
